# Problems with looping and tolower in a basic console application

Tags: c

I'm currently a student learning to code. Our assignment asked us to make a number guessing game. The instructor gave an outline to fill out to help us with the project.

When running this program, it only accepts one guess, prints that the answer is "@" four times, and it does this for the amount of games chosen.

I honestly cannot figure out what I have done wrong. I put the source code below. Any help is appreciated.

For the fopen with the file letterList.txt, I have a text document in the same directory with a list of letters each on a different line.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAXGUESSES 5



//this function provides instructions to the user on how to play the game
void LetterGuessRules();

//this function runs one game.
//input: character from the file, void return type
//all other functions to Play one round of a game
//are called from within the GuessTheLetter function
void GuessTheLetter(char);

//this function prompts the player to make a guess and returns that guess
//this function is called from inside the GuessTheLetter( ) function described above
char GetTheGuess();

//this function takes two arguments, the guess from the player
//and the solution letter from the file.
//The function returns 1 if the guess matches the solution and returns a 0 if they do not match
//This function also lets the user know if the guess comes alphabetically before or after the answer 
int CompareLetters(char, char);

int main()
{
//declare additional variables
//declare FILE pointer
FILE *inPtr;
int numGames = 0, i = 0;
char letter;//letter from file
//display game rules
LetterGuessRules();

//Ask and get number of games to play
printf("\nHow many games would you like to play?\n");
scanf("%d", & numGames);
//connect to the file HINT: use fopen
inPtr = fopen("letterList.txt", "r");

            //this for loop will allow the player to play more than one game
            //without recompiling
for (i = 0; i < numGames; i++)
{
    //get a solution letter from file - use fscanf
    fscanf(inPtr, " %c", &letter);

    //change the solution to lowercase
    letter = tolower(letter);

    //call the GuessTheLetter function and pass it the solution
    GuessTheLetter(inPtr);


}

//close file pointer
return 0;
}

//this function runs one game. 
//input: character from the file, void return type
//all other functions to Play one round of a game 
//are called from within the GuessTheLetter function
//this function lets the user know if they have won or lost the game
void GuessTheLetter(char solution)
{
int win = 0;
int numGuesses = 0;
char playerguess = 0;
//declare additional variables 

while (numGuesses < MAXGUESSES && win == 0)
{
    //get a guess from the user  by calling the GetTheGuess function
    GetTheGuess("playerguess");
    //change the guess to lowercase
    playerguess = tolower;
    printf(" %c", playerguess);
    //win = call the function to compare the guess with the solution
    win = CompareLetters(solution, playerguess);
    numGuesses++;//count the number of guesses so far
}
//use conditions to let the user know if they won or lost the round of the game
if (win == 0)
{
    printf("\nSorry, you lost that round.");
}
else
{
    printf("Congratulations, you won that round");
}
}

//this function provides instructions to the user on how to play the game
void LetterGuessRules()
{
printf("Guess a letter by typing it in then pressing enter.\nThe Game will tell you where your guessed letter is in the alphabet\ncompared to the location of the correct letter.");
}

//this function prompts the player to make a guess and returns that guess
//this function is called from inside the GuessTheLetter( ) function described above
char GetTheGuess(char guess)
{
printf("\nWhat is your guess?\n");
scanf(" %lf", &guess);
return guess;
}

//this function takes two arguments, the guess from the player
//and the solution letter from the file.
//The function returns 1 if the guess matches the solution and returns a 0 if they do not match
//This function also lets the user know if the guess comes alphabetically before or after the answer 
int CompareLetters(char solution, char guess)
{
if (solution == guess)
{
    return 1;
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: How many characters are there in the file `letterList.txt`? Will it always be at least `numGames` characters?

Comment: Also, please don't *start* your output with a newline, *end* with it instead. That's because output written to `stdout` (which is what `printf` writes to) is by default line-buffered. That means a newline will flush the buffer and actually write to the console. If you have a leading newline, it will print the *previous* line, not the current line.

Comment: `GetTheGuess()` returns a value. `playerguess` looks like it meant to hold the value. Your call to `tolower` in `GuessTheLetter` looks very different to all of the others...

Comment: There are a large number of errors in this code.  The first thing to do is start using *function prototypes*  - if a function takes no arguments then put `void` as the parameter list. If you do this in your code then you will start to see some messages thrown up by your compiler that will direct you to where some of the problems are.  Turn up your compiler warning level and fix all of the problems it mentions before running your program.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is this:

```
//get a guess from the user  by calling the GetTheGuess function
GetTheGuess("playerguess");
//change the guess to lowercase
playerguess = tolower;
```

First of all the `GetTheGuess` function call doesn't match the prototype declaration you have. It also doesn't match the actual function implementation. And you don't actually *get* the guess. You also don't call `tolower`, you assign the pointer to the function to the variable `playerguess`.

To correct it, it should look like

```
//get a guess from the user  by calling the GetTheGuess function
playerguess = GetTheGuess(playerguess);  // Note: Not passing a string, and use the returned value
//change the guess to lowercase
playerguess = tolower(playerguess);  // Note: actually call the tolower function
```

You of course need to change the prototype declaration to match the actual definition:

```
char GetTheGuess(char guess);
```

Comment: There isn't even a prototype declaration at the point of the call

Comment: @M.M There is an `char GetTheGuess();` above the `main` function.

Comment: That's a non-prototype declaration, since it has empty parameter list. Hence the lack of a compilation error for the call `GetTheGuess("playerguess");`

Comment: I'm understanding all of and made the changes, but I run into when trying to run it. I asks for the first guess, then asks for the guess 4 more times, but doesn't ask for any inputs. It then says the player lost the round. It does that the amount of times entered when asking how many games the player wants to play. To answer your earlier question, there are only ten letters int the letterList.txt file. The instructor said to use only ten letters.